# How to make multiple pie charts using D3 and a JS dictionary?

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to adapt the code from Mike Bostock's [example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1305111) of making multiple pie charts. It's extremely concise, but I am struggling to understand one basic piece of the code:

```
// Define the data as a two-dimensional array of numbers. If you had other
// data to associate with each number, replace each number with an object, e.g.,
// `{key: "value"}`.
var data = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];
```

What is an example of `{key: "value"}` that makes this work? I've tried

`[{key1: 100}, {key2: 200}]`

`[{key1: 100, key2: 200}]`

`[{'key1': 100, 'key2': 200}]` 
and a few other permutations.

My goal is to use a `json` object instead of a data structure like this, but I want to better understand how to construct the correct data structure.

To generate the chart (via the gist) the following code is used:

```
var m = 10,
    r = 100,
    z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select(".sentiment-pie-chart-1").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", (r + m) * 2)
    .attr("height", (r + m) * 2)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + m) + "," + (r + m) + ")");

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.layout.pie())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(r / 2)
    .outerRadius(r))
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });
```

Comment: Did you happen to solve this by any chance? I am also stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any arbitrary structure (including the ones you've listed) as long as you then also replace the way the pie chart layout extracts the value from this structure. This means that you probably want consistent key names though. For example for the data structure

```
[{key1: 100}, {key1: 200}]
```

you would need to define the pie chart layout as follows using the [`.value()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#wiki-value) -- I assume this is your question.

```
svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) { return d.key1; })
// etc
```

This would take each element in each array (note that you have 2 nested arrays of objects here) and get the member `.key1` to calculate the pie chart fraction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't quite understand how different keys are handled though. If I had data like this `var data = [[{key1: '100'}, {key2: '50'}], [{key1: '200'}, {key2: '70'}]];` do I need to state the specific key name using `.value()` for each key type?

Comment: In this case it wouldn't work like this as the key name for each element is different. You would need something else that tells you which key to get in which context. Usually, you would have everything under the same key.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Pie chart
    </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8' ></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var data = [
                [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
                [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
                [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
                [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
            ];

            //For the data above you can convert each data row in array of object.
            //like,

            var newData = data[0].map(function(val){
                return {value : val} ;
            });

            //here you will get  : 

            // var newData = [
            //     {value : 11975} ,
            //     {value : 5871} ,
            //     {value : 8916} ,
            //     {value : 2868} ];

            // You can do same thing for each data row  .

            var width = 1100 , height = 650 , radius = 250 ,
            color = ["#C5AAF5","#FB7374","#A3CBF1","#79BFA1","#F5A352","#94B3C8", "#F9D08B","#B2AC4E","#64BD4F","#C09372"];

            var colorDescriptions = [];

            var svgContainer = d3.select("body") // create svg container
                .append("svg:svg")
                .data([newData])
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 + "," + 300 + ")") ;;

            // Create new svg containier for each element && transform it to diff point.
            var arc = d3.svg.arc() // draw arc of given radius
                .outerRadius(radius);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie() // assign data for pie chart
                .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

            var arcs = svgContainer.selectAll("g.slice") // slice the circle
                .data(pie)   
                .enter()
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "slice");

            arcs.append("svg:path") // fill color in each slice
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; } )
                .attr("d", arc)

            arcs.append("svg:text") // write slice information values
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius;
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d, i) { return newData[i].value; })
                .style("font-family","monospace")
                .style("fill", "#3f3f3f")
                .style("font-size", "20px");

            var description = svgContainer.append("g").attr("class", "description"); // pie chart description
            var desc_label = description.append("text")
                .attr("class", "description")
                .attr("y", 300)
                .attr("x", 000)
                .text("Pie Chart")
                .style("font-weight", "bold")
                .style("font-size", "20px")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle"); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```